# EXCEL VBA: Copy Sheet from a workbook to another workbook in different location

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a whole sheet from one Excel file to a sheet in another. Following is the code I wrote which doesn't work. Please suggest changes.

```
Sub copyallwos()

Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim shttocopy As Worksheet
Dim wbname As String

Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\AV\Documents\New folder\SCADA Wos.xlsm")

Set wkbDest = Workbooks("C:\Users\AV\Documents\New folder\MASTER.xlsm")

'perform copy
Set shttocopy = wkbSource.Sheets("tt")
shttocopy.Copy
wkbDest.Sheets("SCADAWOs").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this under `'perform copy`

```
wkbSource.Sheets("tt").Copy After:=wkbDest.Sheets("SCADAWOs")
```

You can also insert the sheet before your "SCAD..." sheet, just change `After:=` to `Before:=`.  Also, if you don't necessarily know a sheet name in the destination workbook, you can use `After:=Wkbdest.sheets(sheets.count)` which will instert it after the last Worksheet.

Comment: Thankyou. I will try it. I am also getting a 'script out of range' error on this line: Set wkbDest = Workbooks("C:\Users\AV\Documents\New folder\MASTER.xlsm")

Comment: @ArunNoelVictor - silly question, but that is exactly where the file is, and named correct? and it's an .xlsm extension?

Comment: Hm - I tested similar code on my comp. and it opened without an issue.  Try just moving it to C:\, and see if it can open from there? Or some other folder to test.

Comment: I had to open the wkbDest  for this to work, otherwise I was also getting "out of range" error